# Sonatype Nexus: Multiple email addresses be specified in the 'Alert email' field of Scheduled tasks configuration?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, nexus, sonatype

Is it possible to have multiple email addresses in the *Alert Email* field of Scheduled tasks configuration? if so, should it be separated by a comma?

[image: Scheduled Tasks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one email address is supported. In general I would suggest to create a mailing list for all Nexus administrators, that you manage externally. That way you can easily add and remove recipients without having to reconfigure anything in Nexus and it will be applicable in a number of configurations in Nexus itself as well as a general means for users to contact the Nexus administration team.